# Docker php как работать с почтой

Tags: php, docker, email, docker-compose

я начал изучать docker. Столкнулся с тем ,что мне нужно в php отправлять почту.
Но как это сделать через docker?

Я использую docker-compose с таким конфигом

```js
version: '3'

services: 
  web:  
    build: ./web
    environment: 
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
    volumes: 
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456

  composer:
    image: composer:1.6
    volumes: 
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install

  phpmyadmin:
    build: ./phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
```

Comment: я думаю этот вопрос к докеру имеет мало отношения, т.к. почту будет отправлять ваш код на `php` через `smtp` сервер, а не `docker`, ищите примеры как это делать на `php`.

Comment: Если использовать open server, то там есть вкладка почта, в которой это дело можно настроить. И тогда в php посредством использования обычной функции mail можно отправлять почту. Мне кажется логичным, что в docker тоже можно настроить это